# How to generate OAuth2 access token to access Salesforce REST APIs from Postman

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, salesforce, postman

It is really hard to figure out, from documentation, the steps to generate an access token for accessing the Salesforce REST APIs. What are the steps to be followed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner and want to try out the APIs then follow the below steps,

1. Create an account in developer.salesforce.com
2. Create a connected app
3. Enable OAuth access
4. Give required access permissions to the app (start with full access)
5. Save the consumer key and consumer secret
6. Create a `Permission Set` with API access and associate the `Permission Set` with the `User`
7. Go to `Settings > Network access` and give the Trusted IP range (your machine's IP)
8. Go to the Connected app and change the OAuth access policies,

   (a) All users may self-authorize

   (b) Relax IP restrictions

Next, to generate access token in Postman

Choose OAuth2 authorization and use the following details to generate an access token

```
grant_type: password
access_token_url: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
username: <registerd username to log in to developer.salesforce.com>
password: <password used to log in to developer.salesforce.com>
client_id: <consumer key generated in step 5>
client_secret: <consumer secret generated in step 5>
scope: <empty>
client_authentication: send client credentials in body
```

Use the `instance_url` from access token response to build the REST API URLs

Example: GET https://na123.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Case/

That's it. You are good to go!